# Reset Firebase assistant to initial state

Tags: android, firebase

I have many issues with google authentication with firebase. I need to change the account of it, but even when I make this change I still occur some bugs. I would like to reset firebase to 0, and from this position add everything one more time.

How to delete this Connected sign to make it one more time?
Why is it connected, how to delete it?

[AuthenticationPictutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcIep.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and refer to option 1 to remove the dependencies and plugins stated and sync the project which helps to remove the connected status.